# Subscriber when a group is assigned to an user

Tags: plone, plone-3.x

When assigning a user to a group, is it possible to call a [subscriber](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/set-up-subscriber-in-five)? Are there available [events](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-community-developer-documentation/events-and-rules/events) to this action? If so, in which product?

Comment: For those who may not be familiar with events in Plone, could you please add a bit more detail? E.g. "in my app I am currently using events to do XYZ; can I also use them to do ABC?"

Comment: Why the -1? The question is really straightforward, the only answer even perfectly properly addressed the problem.

Comment: For the reasons I mentioned in my comment :-) Looks like someone fixed up the question though, cool.

Comment: I've edited myself and added some links. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It does not appear that Products.PluggableAuthService.plugins.ZODBGroupManager.ZODBGroupManager.addPrincipalToGroup nor anything that calls it notifies any event.

I would suggest that if you have an add-on that needs this:

(1) Submit a feature request ticket at https://dev.plone.org -- it would be nice to have this, I am pretty sure that I could use it too.

(2) For now, have your add-on monkey patch ZODBGroupManager.addPrincipalToGroup() method wrapping the original function with an event notification of your own devising called after the user is added to the group.  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=monkey+patch+python

Comment: Yes, PAS still does not do this now.  You are always welcome to either monkey patch or sign Zope Foundation contributor agreement if you wish to submit an improvement via github pull request.  https://github.com/zopefoundation/Products.PluggableAuthService/blob/master/Products/PluggableAuthService/plugins/ZODBGroupManager.py#L267